# Is ROS Kinetic compatible with libopencv-dev-2.4.9?

Tags: ros, opencv, libopencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [REP link](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) suggests to use opencv 3.1.x with ROS Kinetic. However, since the system package libopencv-dev 3.1.x version isn't available in the upstream ubuntu repository yet, I had installed libopencv-dev 2.4.9 which was already in my cache and implemented [cv_bridge tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages). It seemed to be working fine without any issues.

1. So, can I safely assume that ROS Kinetic is compatible with opencv2 as well or is there any other check I need to look out for which would break this compatibility that I'm assuming ?
2. and if version 3.1.x is a must, can I build Opencv 3.1 with CUDA support as documented [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d15/tutorial_building_tegra_cuda.html)?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 , ARM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258504/is-ros-kinetic-compatible-with-libopencv-dev-2.4.9?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS packages a custom version of OpenCV3 for Kinetic; it does not use the system version. The [opencv3 wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3?distro=kinetic) describes this and the reasoning behind it in more detail.

I don't think the pre-compiled version of OpenCV3 will have CUDA support, since the pre-built binaries are typically built for the lowest common denominator platform.

Building OpenCV3 from source will probably work, but keep in mind that if you want to avoid ABI breakages and the very strange crashes that they can cause, you'll also need to build everything that depends on OpenCV3 from source, to make sure that it's compatible with your version. At a minimum, this will include the cv_bridge, image_pipeline and image_transport packages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1